# QGIS: Finding electric network loops

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

With QGIS, how can we analyse an electrical network to find loops?
Using Python is not a problem, however there is not a solution in the QGIS Python API.

The QgsGraphAnalyzer has dijkstra and shortestTree functions, but no loop finding function ([QgsGraphAnalyzer Class Reference](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGraphAnalyzer.html)).

Example:
The image below includes 2 vector layers with wires that connect electrically. The loop is an error - it can't exist in a radial distribution network.
Is it possible to find these loops using QGIS and Python?

[image: Loop Example]

Answer (score 1):

You could try the **Polygonize** tool in the QGIS Processing Toolbox. If you ran this on your example (after appending the two tables together) the loop would be identified by the presence of a polygon in the output dataset.